# Clonned Select2 is not responding

Tags: javascript, clone, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in a `bootstrap form-group` which contains one `datepicker` and one select2. When I cloned the form-group only the `datepicker` can work, the select2 can't work at all.

I almost try all the answer on stackoverflow, every time I try, it will display different error, like **"style error"**, **"event can't work"**, **"click the cloned select2 but responsed to the origin select2"**.

My code is as following:

*HTML code:*

```
    <div class="form-group drive-item">
      <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">试驾时间: </label>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="col-md-3 has-feedback">
              <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left drive-date" name="drive_date" placeholder="试驾日期" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
              <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <select class="select2_one form-control select2-gentlla" tabindex="-1" name="drive_time" multiple="multiple">
                <option value=""></option>
                <foreach name="hour_list" item="hour">
                  <option value="{$hour}">{$hour}</option>
                </foreach>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-margin"></span>
      </fieldset>
  </div>
```

*The JS code:*

```
$('.drive-item').on('click', '.glyphicon-plus', function(){
  $form_group = $(this).parent().parent();
  $clone = $form_group.clone();

  $datepicker = $clone.find('.drive-date');
  $datepicker.daterangepicker('destroy');
  $datepicker.removeAttr('id');
  $datepicker.daterangepicker(datepicker_option);

  $select2_origin = $form_group.find('.select2_one');
  $select2_origin.select2('destroy');

  $select2_clone = $select2_origin.clone();
  console.log($select2_origin);
  console.log($select2_clone);

  $form_group.after($clone);

  $select2_origin.select2();
  $select2_clone.select2();

});
```

Any help/suggestion will be appreciable.

I solved this problem after read this thread:
[Select2 clone is working only twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252443/select2-clone-is-working-only-twice)

Comment: Solve this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252443/select2-clone-is-working-only-twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252443/select2-clone-is-working-only-twice)

Comment: If you solved, please, answer to you question, expose what you did yo solve the question, instead of edit your post and put in their the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The clone you made has the exact same markup as the original. So calling .select2() on it won't know which one to initialize and will error.

use

```
$('select').select2();
```

This will initialize all instances of `<select>` on the page

Comment: I tried this, it will add additional input <element>